# Hadoop Pig fs test command

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Wondering what does this line mean? Searched around but cannot find a reference for this command,

```
Pig.fs("test -e " + pathToCheck) == 0:
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Probably testing for existence of regex paths based on how it looks. I also guess this is already deprecated in current version, since you can't find any reference.

Comment: @Mai, thanks, vote up and -e equal to zero means exist or not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command line tool and run `hadoop fs -help` and got :

```
-test -[defsz] <path> :
  Answer various questions about <path>, with result via exit status.
    -d  return 0 if <path> is a directory.
    -e  return 0 if <path> exists.
    -f  return 0 if <path> is a file.
    -s  return 0 if file <path> is greater than zero bytes in size.
    -z  return 0 if file <path> is zero bytes in size, else return 1.
```

Comment: Thanks Mzf for the reference and vote up. How hadoop fs related to Pig.fs?

Comment: it make sense that pig fs command is hdfs command, also can see the documentation http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/cmds.html#fs - when you press on the link "File System Shell Guide" it will lead you to hadoop file system command

Comment: Thanks for the help Mzf, vote up and mark your reply as an answer.